# CountDownTimer adds time with each loop

Tags: java, android-fragments, countdowntimer

I'm working on a fragment that includes two timers that take user input. Timer B is linked to timer A such that when timer A is started, so is timer B. The purpose of timer A is to count down once. The purpose of timer B is to count down, beep once at 0, reset to the original value, and repeat. The problem I'm having is that when timer B reaches 0, it doesn't reset and start counting down right away. The timer seems to be delayed further by calling ToneGenerator. This results in the two timers becoming more and more out of sync each time timer B resets.

For example, say timer A is set to 10 seconds and timer B is set to 2 seconds.

-The timers are started-

timer A:10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

timer B: 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1

The timer only beeps 3 times (when timer B is at 0,) when it should beep 5 times (5 sets of 2 second intervals = 10 seconds: the value of timer A.) In other words, I'd like timer B to beep when timer A is at 8, 6, 4, 2, and 0.

How might I accomplish this?

I've consulted the forums, YT, and have tried playing around with the value for millisInFuture.

**Fragment**

```
public class fragmentdro extends Fragment {
    private EditText session_edit_text;
    private EditText dro_edit_text;
    private TextView session_text_view;
    private TextView dro_text_view;
    private Button session_start_button;
    private Button dro_start_button;
    private Button session_reset_button;
    private Button dro_reset_button;
    private Button session_set_button;
    private Button dro_set_button;
    private CountDownTimer sessionTimer;
    private CountDownTimer droTimer;
    private boolean SessionTimerRunning;
    private boolean DROTimerRunning;
    private long SessionStartTimeInMillis;
    private long DROStartTimeInMillis;
    private long SessionTimeLeftInMillis = SessionStartTimeInMillis;
    private long DROTimeLeftInMillis = DROStartTimeInMillis;
    private long SessionEndTime;
    private long DROEndTime;
    View View;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @NonNull ViewGroup container, @NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dro_fragment, container, false);

        session_edit_text = View.findViewById(R.id.session_edit_text);
        dro_edit_text = View.findViewById(R.id.dro_edit_text);
        session_text_view = View.findViewById(R.id.session_text_view);
        dro_text_view = View.findViewById(R.id.dro_text_view);
        session_start_button = View.findViewById(R.id.session_start_button);
        dro_start_button = View.findViewById(R.id.dro_start_button);
        session_reset_button = View.findViewById(R.id.session_reset_button);
        dro_reset_button = View.findViewById(R.id.dro_reset_button);
        session_set_button = View.findViewById(R.id.session_set_button);
        dro_set_button = View.findViewById(R.id.dro_set_button);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        ToneGenerator toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
```

**Timer A**

```
session_set_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(android.view.View view) {
                String Sessioninput = session_edit_text.getText().toString();
                if (Sessioninput.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fill it in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                long millisInput = Long.parseLong(Sessioninput) * 1000;
                if (millisInput == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter a positive number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                setSessionTime(millisInput);
                session_edit_text.setText("");
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });

        session_start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(android.view.View view) {
                if (SessionTimerRunning) {
                    pauseSessionTimer();
                    resetDROTimer();
                } else {
                    startSessionTimer();
                    startDROTimer();
                }
            }
        });

        session_reset_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(android.view.View view) {
                if (SessionTimerRunning) {
                    resetSessionTimer();
                } else {
                    resetSessionTimer();
                }
            }
        });

  public void setSessionTime(long milliseconds) {
        SessionStartTimeInMillis = milliseconds;
        resetSessionTimer();
    }

    public void startSessionTimer() {
        SessionEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + SessionTimeLeftInMillis;
        sessionTimer = new CountDownTimer(SessionTimeLeftInMillis, 100) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                SessionTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateSessionText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                SessionTimerRunning = false;
                session_start_button.setText("Start");
                session_start_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
                session_reset_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }.start();

        SessionTimerRunning = true;
        session_start_button.setText("Pause");
    }

    public void pauseSessionTimer() {
        sessionTimer.cancel();
        droTimer.cancel();
        SessionTimerRunning = false;
        DROTimerRunning = false;
        session_start_button.setText("Start");
        updateSessionText();
    }

    public void resetSessionTimer() {
        if (SessionTimerRunning) {
            sessionTimer.cancel();
            SessionTimeLeftInMillis = (SessionStartTimeInMillis);
            updateSessionInterface();
            startSessionTimer();
        } else {
            SessionTimeLeftInMillis = (SessionStartTimeInMillis);
            updateSessionText();
            updateSessionInterface();
            session_reset_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            session_start_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void updateSessionText() {
        int minutes = (int) (SessionTimeLeftInMillis/1000/60);
        int seconds = (int) (SessionTimeLeftInMillis/1000)%60;

        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%2d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
        session_text_view.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }

    public void updateSessionInterface() {
        if (SessionTimerRunning) {
            session_edit_text.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
            session_set_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
            session_reset_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            session_start_button.setText("Pause");
        } else {
            session_edit_text.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            session_set_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            session_reset_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            session_start_button.setText("Start");
        }
    }
```

**Timer B**

```
dro_set_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(android.view.View view) {
                String DROinput = dro_edit_text.getText().toString();
                if (DROinput.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fill it in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                long millisInput = Long.parseLong(DROinput) * 1000;
                if (millisInput == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter a positive number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                setDROTime(millisInput);
                dro_edit_text.setText("");
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });

        dro_start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(android.view.View view) {
                if (DROTimerRunning) {
                    pauseDROTimer();
                } else {
                    startDROTimer();
                }
            }
        });

        dro_reset_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(android.view.View view) {
                if (DROTimerRunning) {
                    resetDROTimer();
                } else {
                    resetDROTimer();
                }
            }
        });
  return View;
    }
public void setDROTime(long milliseconds) {
        DROStartTimeInMillis = milliseconds;
        resetDROTimer();
    }

    public void startDROTimer() {
        DROEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + DROTimeLeftInMillis;
        droTimer = new CountDownTimer(DROTimeLeftInMillis, 100) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                DROTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateDROText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                ToneGenerator toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 400);
                toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);
                DROTimerRunning = false;
                DROTimeLeftInMillis = DROStartTimeInMillis;
                updateDROText();
                updateDROInterface();
                startDROTimer();
            }
        }.start();

        DROTimerRunning = true;
        dro_start_button.setText("Pause");
    }

    public void pauseDROTimer() {
        droTimer.cancel();
        DROTimerRunning = false;
        dro_start_button.setText("Start");
        updateDROText();
    }

    public void resetDROTimer() {
        if (DROTimerRunning) {
            droTimer.cancel();
            DROTimeLeftInMillis = (DROStartTimeInMillis);
            updateDROInterface();
            startDROTimer();
        } else {
            DROTimeLeftInMillis = (DROStartTimeInMillis);
            updateDROText();
            updateDROInterface();
            dro_reset_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            dro_start_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void updateDROText() {
        int seconds = (int) (DROTimeLeftInMillis/1000)%60;

        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), ":%02d", seconds));
        dro_text_view.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }

    public void updateDROInterface() {
        if (DROTimerRunning) {
            dro_edit_text.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
            dro_set_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
            dro_reset_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            dro_start_button.setText("Pause");
        } else {
            dro_edit_text.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            dro_set_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            dro_reset_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            dro_start_button.setText("Start");
        }
    }
 @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putLong("SessionStartTimeInMillis", SessionStartTimeInMillis);
        editor.putLong("DROStartTimeInMillis", DROStartTimeInMillis);
        editor.putLong("MillisLeft", SessionTimeLeftInMillis);
        editor.putLong("DROMillisLeft", DROTimeLeftInMillis);
        editor.putBoolean("TimerRunning", SessionTimerRunning);
        editor.putBoolean("DROTimerRunning", DROTimerRunning);
        editor.putLong("EndTime", SessionEndTime);
        editor.putLong("DROEndTime", DROEndTime);

        if (sessionTimer !=null); {
            sessionTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SessionStartTimeInMillis = preferences.getLong("SessionStartTimeInMillis", 0);
        SessionTimeLeftInMillis = preferences.getLong("MillisLeft", SessionTimeLeftInMillis);
        SessionTimerRunning = preferences.getBoolean("TimerRunning", false);

        DROStartTimeInMillis = preferences.getLong("DROStartTimeInMillis", 0);
        DROTimeLeftInMillis = preferences.getLong("DROMillisLeft", DROTimeLeftInMillis);
        DROTimerRunning = preferences.getBoolean("DROTimerRunning", false);

        updateSessionText();
        updateSessionInterface();
        updateDROText();
        updateDROInterface();

        if (SessionTimerRunning) {
            SessionEndTime = preferences.getLong("EndTime", 0);
            SessionTimeLeftInMillis = SessionEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (SessionTimeLeftInMillis <0) {
                SessionTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
                SessionTimerRunning = false;
            } else {
                startSessionTimer();
            }
        }

        if (DROTimerRunning) {
            DROEndTime = preferences.getLong("EndTime", 0);
            DROTimeLeftInMillis = DROEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (DROTimeLeftInMillis <0) {
                DROTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
                DROTimerRunning = false;
            } else {
                startDROTimer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```